# Instance validation error: '2' is not a valid value for QueryType. (web service)

Tags: c#, web-services, enums, wsdl

I have a web service that I am passing an enum

```
public enum QueryType {
    Inquiry = 1
    Maintainence = 2
}
```

When I pass an object that has a Parameter of QueryType on it, I get the error back from the web service saying:

> '2' is not a valid value for QueryType

when you can clearly see from the declaration of the enum that it is.

I cannot change the values of the enum because legacy applications use the values, but I would rather not have to insert a "default" value just to push the index of the enum to make it work with my web service. It acts like the web service is using the index of the values rather than the values themselves.

Does anybody have a suggestion of what I can do to make it work, is there something I can change in my WSDL?

Comment: Are you sure the binary files in the web service are up-to-date?  I've seen stuff like this when I compile a libary project and forget to copy the DLL to the web service folders.

Comment: No, I'm not sure, however I know the signature of that enum has not changed. Could that still cause this issue? I will try to update the web service with the most up to date DLL and see if that makes a difference. Thanks Paul!

Comment: Paul, unfortunately that did not work. It really seems like it's trying to take the zero index of the enum rather than by value

Comment: Is there another QueryType enum somewhere?  The MSDN help says there is one in Microsoft.SharePoint.Dsp.

Comment: I'm not sure. What I ended up doing for the interim until I have more time to play with it, is casting it's value to an int and passing the int to the service and then recasting it back as the QueryType on the web service side. Seems to work alright that way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using asmx web services for this answer.

Your guess is right -- the XML Serializer uses the enumeration names in the WSDL and not the value.

If you look at your WSDL it will look something like this:

```
<s:simpleType name="QueryType">
  <s:restriction base="s:string">
    <s:enumeration value="Inquiry" /> 
    <s:enumeration value="Maintainence" /> 
  </s:restriction>
</s:simpleType>
```

So, when you invoke the service it is expecting a string that is the name of the enumeration member.  When you use a .NET proxy, this conversion is usually handled for you.  If a value is passed to the service that cannot be deserialized into the enum value you will get the message that you are seeing.

To get around this, you can ensure you are sending it the expected value or, if that doesn't work for you, you can tell the XML Serializer what values you want to use.  You can do this using the XmlEnum attribute:

```
public enum QueryType 
{
    [XmlEnum("1")]
    Inquiry = 1,
    [XmlEnum("2")]
    Maintainence = 2
}
```

This will generate the following schema fragment (from the WSDL):

```
<s:simpleType name="QueryType">
  <s:restriction base="s:string">
    <s:enumeration value="1" /> 
    <s:enumeration value="2" /> 
  </s:restriction>
</s:simpleType>
```

Then if you are passing the value "2" into the service then it should be deserialized properly but you lose the meaning of the enumeration values.

Comment: Unfortunately, this also did not change the error that I received.

Comment: I will try to post up a better code sample of what I'm working with. Maybe it's something wierd that we're doing in our DLL and web service.

Comment: Yes, please provide a sample.

Comment: This resolved my issue.  My question is, I had to do this to code that has existed for quite some time.  I'm wondering what could have changed that caused me to have to add the XMLEnum to my enum values?

Comment: This just happened to me, too, and my code had existed for some time. Very strange.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the `Flags()` attribute to the QueryType definition.

Answer (score 0):

Something to consider is to make sure that you initialize your enum values and not assume the first item from your list will be used.

For example, having an enum defined that does not start at the int value of 0 such as this:

```
 public enum EnumCategoryID
        {
            TOOTH_PASTE = 1,
            TOOTH_BRUSHES = 2,
            HOT_BEVERAGES = 3,
            ENERGY_DRINKS = 4,
            OVER_THE_COUNTER = 5,
            IN_STORE = 6
        }
```

Normally when you declare your enum instance you may be tempted to do this:

```
EnumCategoryID anID; //Assuming the value will be 'TOOTH_PASTE' when used
```

If the data structure that you return through the webservice has a enum variable attached to it you WILL receive the instance error if called from outside the webservice (but if you use the dataclass from within the webservice you will have no errors).

Point is, just be sure that you have properly initialized your enum instance that you are returning in the webservice.

Comment: if you look back at the original question, the values were being initialized. Once it was sent to the web service, the web service was ignoring the values and using he enum names.